# How can I list all the current entries in my apache vhosts file for display on my dev site's default web page?

Tags: apache, redhat, vhosts

I've got a dev server with loads of sites running on it, and it changes weekly. Instead of constantly updating my default web page to provide links to it, I want to have a dynamic list.

Basically, I want to display

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example1.dev.ourdomain.com">example1.dev.ourdomain.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example1.staging.ourdomain.com">example1.dev.ourdomain.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example2.dev.ourdomain.com">example2.dev.ourdomain.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example2.staging.ourdomain.com">example2.dev.ourdomain.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

dynamically for our developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a very simple site, only links to the websites, I'm just going to use html with server side includes.

1) I'll need this in an apache config (such as /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf):

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

crontab to pull out the urls and create links from them:

```
30 2 * * * /usr/sbin/httpd -S | egrep -i 'ourdomain.com' | egrep -i 'namevhost' | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9A-Za-z.-]*\.ourdomain\.com\).*/<li><a href="http:\/\/\1">\1<\/a><\/li>/i' > /websites/ourdomain/current_sites.html
```

(one problem... this is all just the namevhost entries, I might have to be more specific)

3) Create an html page at /websites/ourdomain/index.shtml

```
<html><body>
   <h3>This list is compiled from the current VHOST entries every night at 2:30 am</h3>
   <ul class="links">
     <!--#include virtual="current_sites.html" -->
   </ul>
</body></html>
```

4) Update the vhosts file to default to this whenever someone types anything we haven't already handled at dev.ourdomain.com (this is not all necessary, just our setup)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName dev.ourdomain.com
  ServerAlias *.dev.ourdomain.com

  DocumentRoot /websites/ourdomain
  <Directory /websites/ourdomain>
    # This relaxes Apache security settings.
    AllowOverride all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews
    Options +Includes
    # Redirects
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /websites/ourdomain
  </Directory>

  # Our security group
  <Location />
    Require user admin
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I think that's it.